# site - is currently unable to handle this request Http error 500

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, http-error-500

once i clicked on "Proceed to checkout" button, we are getting below error

**The sitename.com is't working 

www.sitename.co.nz is currently unable to handle this request 

Http Error 500**

even in backend when we open some orders, than also same error in order-view page.

we are using `hostgator` for shared hosting.

**Edit**

It was the problem with one of checkout related file reset to `000` permission. once i gave 644 permission, it again start to work. but this problem is happening frequently.

**why file is resetting to 000 permission**

Comment: Check your server error log and post the error here

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism we are using shared hosting. i am trying to contact the hosting providers. will check and let you know soon

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism can we find server error through cpanel  in hostgator?

Comment: Well look for error logs but i reckon it depends on the type of user your hosting company provided you

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism when i looked for errors folder, it showed empty.

Comment: You won't find it then you'll have to ask your provider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

500 errors should be in the webservice error log or possibly a PHP error log if you have one. It could be any number of things and its impossible to diagnose from the frontend, unfortunately.  HG support might be able to provide access to those logs.